# .Net Core Fluent Validation With React Or Angular

Tags: angular, react-native, asp.net-core, validation, asp.net-core-webapi

When using .net core mvc, validation errors related to an entity related to that entity can be received with "asp-validator-for", with the same logic, how is this process done in angular or especially in react. (SPA)

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When using .net core mvc, validation errors related to an entity
> related to that entity can be received with "asp-validator-for"

In asp.net core MVC, when using .Net core built-in model validation or Fluent Validation, it is the server-side validation. To implement client-side validation, [Tag Helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and [HTML helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-7.0) use the validation attributes and type metadata from model properties to render HTML 5 `data-` attributes for the form elements that need validation. [jQuery Unobtrusive Validation](https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive) parses the `data-` attributes and passes the logic to jQuery Validation, effectively "copying" the server-side validation logic to the client. More detail information, see [Client-side validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0#client-side-validation).

In the SPA Angular or React application, if you want to use the same process like in the MVC application, you have to add the custom attribute and add the client-side validation by yourself. I'm not suggest you using that method, you can directly use the [jQuery Unobtrusive Validation](https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive) and [jQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) in the angular/react components and implement the client-side validation.

Comment: Thank you very much for the valuable information you have shared.
As a result, when fluent validation is used in a .net web api application, will it be enough to return only a message.   (for SPA Agular or react)

Comment: RuleFor(a => a.CarId)
                .NotEmpty().WithMessage(v => ValidatorOptions.Global.LanguageManager.GetString("NotEmptyValidator"))
                                    .NotNull().WithMessage(v => ValidatorOptions.Global.LanguageManager.GetString("NotNullValidator"))               RuleFor(a => a.plate)
                 .NotEmpty().WithMessage(v => ValidatorOptions.Global.LanguageManager.GetString("NotEmptyValidator"))
                               .NotNull().WithMessage(v => ValidatorOptions.Global.LanguageManager.GetString("NotNullValidator"))

Comment: "when fluent validation is used in a .net web api application, will it be enough to return only a message.", Yes, when use fluent validation in web api application, it will return the validation error message.